# Constructing a binary tree in java

Tags: java, object-oriented, tree

I am constructing a binary tree. Let me know if this is a right way to do it. If not please tell me how to?? I could not find a proper link where constructing a general binary tree has been coded. Everywhere BST is coded.

```
  3
 / \
1   4
   / \
  2   5
```

This is the binary tree which i want to make.I should be able to do all the tree traversals.Simple stuff.

```
public class Binarytreenode
{
    public Binarytreenode left;
    public Binarytreenode right;
    public int data;

    public Binarytreenode(int data)
    {
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void printNode()
    {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Binarytreenode root = new Binarytreenode(3);
        Binarytreenode n1 = new Binarytreenode(1);
        Binarytreenode n2 = new Binarytreenode(4);
        Binarytreenode n3 = new Binarytreenode(2);
        Binarytreenode n4 = new Binarytreenode(5);

        root.left = n1;
        root.right = n2;
        root.right.left = n3;
        root.right.right = n4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to be able to construct arbitrary trees, you could introduce some convenience functions:

```
public static Binarytreenode n(int datum) {
    return new Binarytreenode(datum);
}

public static Binarytreenode n(Binarytreenode left, int datum, Binarytreenode right) {
    Binarytreenode root = n(datum);
    root.left = left;
    root.right = right;
    return root;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Binarytreenode root = n(n(1), 3, n(n(2), 4, n(5)));
}
```

With the right imagination, you can visualize the tree in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does represent the tree that you drew.  However, the code doesn't implement the logic for determining *where* to place nodes within a binary search tree; instead, you hard-coded that logic in your `main()` function.  A useful implementation of `Binarytreenode` would let you write something like

```
BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree();
t.add(3);
t.add(1);
t.add(4);
t.add(2);
t.add(5);
```

… to produce the same tree structure.

---

You want to design the code as a class that maintains the tree in a self-consistent state, supporting operations such as `.add(int value)` and `.find(int value)`.  The member fields `left`, `right`, and `data` should generally not be have `public` access, which would let other code modify the tree in an invalid way.  It could be acceptable, however, to let `data` remain `public` if you also mark it as `final`.

Comment: I understand your point but  I dont want a BST. I just want a binary tree , which does not have a logic for adding nodes. How to do that??